# Text Mining Cleanup with Ruby & Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, text, text-mining

I have a word count hash, something as the following:

```
words = {
  "love"   => 10,
  "hate"   => 12,
  "lovely" => 3,
  "loving" => 2,
  "loved"  => 1, 
  "peace"  => 14,
  "thanks" => 3,
  "wonderful" => 10,
  "grateful" => 10
  # there are more but you get the idea
}
```

I want to make sure that "love", "loved" & "loving" are all counted as "love". So I am adding all their counts together to be the count for "love", and removing the rest of the variation of "love". However, at the same time, I don't want "lovely" to be counted as "love", so I am preserving it as it is.

So I'll get something like this in the end.

```
words = [
  "love"   => 13,
  "hate"   => 12,
  "lovely" => 3,
  "peace"  => 14,
  "thanks" => 3,
  "wonderful" => 10,
  "grateful" => 10
  # there are more but you get the idea
]
```

I have some code that sort of works, but I think the logic of the last line is really wrong. I wonder if you can help me fix this or suggest a better way of doing this.

```
words.select { |k| /\Alov[a-z]*/.match(k) }
words["love"] = purgedWordCount.select { |k| /\Alov[a-z]*/.match(k) }.map(&:last).reduce(:+) - 1 # that 1 is for the 1 for "lovely"; I tried not to hard code it by using words["lovely"], but it messed things up completely, so I had to do this. 
words.delete_if { |k| /\Alov[a-z]*/.match(k) && k != "love" && k != "lovely" }
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's some pretty rough Ruby. Are you sure it's not `words = { ... }`?

Comment: @tadman sorry that's a typo. I'll fix it. but yes it's super messy.

Comment: Why the rush in selecting an answer? Seeing the green checkmark flash on so soon after the question was posted is just a bit annoying to those still preparing answers. Also, quick-draw checkmarks can discourage other, possibly better, answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for pointing it out. I'm new here, so I'm not sure if I'm expected to pick an answer fast so that people can help with other people's problems. I'll wait for a while the next time.

Comment: @practicemakesperfect The selected answer can always be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = {
  "love"   => 10,
  "hate"   => 12,
  "lovely" => 3,
  "loving" => 2,
  "loved"  => 1,
  "peace"  => 14,
  "thanks" => 3,
  "wonderful" => 10,
  "grateful" => 10
  # there are more but you get the idea
}

aggregated_words = words.inject({}) do |memo, (word, count)|
  key = word =~ /\Alov.+/ && word != "lovely" ? "love" : word
  memo[key] = memo[key].to_i + count
  memo
end

> {"love"=>13, "hate"=>12, "lovely"=>3, "peace"=>14, "thanks"=>3, "wonderful"=>10, "grateful"=>10}
```

Comment: This could be one regular expression with a negative assertion.

Comment: @tadman What do you think of /\Alov(?!ely).+\z/ ? I don't see how to do this with a negative assertion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
r = /
    lov     # match 'lov'
    (?!ely) # negative lookahead to not match 'ely'
    [a-z]+  # match one or more letters
            # /x is for 'extended', /i makes it case-independent
    /xi

words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v),h| (k=~r) ? h["love"]+=v : h[k]=v }
  #=> {"love"=>13, "hate"=>12, "lovely"=>3, "peace"=>14, "thanks"=>3,
  #    "wonderful"=>10, "grateful"=>10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the functional non destructive version

```
words = {
  "love"   => 10,
  "hate"   => 12,
  "lovely" => 3,
  "loving" => 2,
  "loved"  => 1, 
  "peace"  => 14,
  "thanks" => 3,
  "wonderful" => 10,
  "grateful" => 10
}

to_love_or_not_to_love = words.partition {|w| w.first =~ /^lov/ && w.first != "lovely"}

{"love" => to_love_or_not_to_love.first.map(&:last).sum}.merge(to_love_or_not_to_love.last.reduce({}) {|m, e| m[e.first] = e.last; m})
```

=> {"love"=>13, "hate"=>12, "lovely"=>3, "peace"=>14, "thanks"=>3, "wonderful"=>10, "grateful"=>10

Comment: You've included `lovely` in the `love` sum. That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: When you edit, please format so that horizontal scrolling is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are dealing with big enough vocabulary, what you really need here is a stemmer, not just a regex. Making a hash of stems will be easy and elegant solution.

Simple one for english [here](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/ruby.txt), but there are a number of gems for this purpose and different languages.

Comment: This is on the borderline between an answer and a comment. I would have made it a comment, but others may disagree.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I was considering stemming, but stemming looks too drastic for me. While "love" and "lovely" share the same root, its meaning varies greatly. Since my dataset it rather small, I don't mind doing some manual work by reading them

Comment: A stemmer based on a good English lexigraphical dictionary would be able to distinguish between the forms of "love" (verb) and "lovely" (adj.). Something like [Ruby-wordnet](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet/) might not be that much effort to incorporate.